# what is the good way to organize ad-related code?

Tags: ios, delegates, ads

I'm working on an iOS app that has multiple views/viewcontrollers. In three of these views, I want to display ads. What's a good practice to organize my code?

To display an ad, I usually import its delegate in the viewController.h file and implement its delegate methods in the corresponding .m file. But now, I need the ad in multiple viewcontrollers, so I need put ad-related codes in each and every .h file of these viewcontrollers. Apparently, it's not a good organizational method: too much repetitive codes.

How should I organize the ad-related codes? Or say good way to organize for delegate methods.

Comment: Try To display an ad at appDelegate only using a **window**...

Comment: Use Custom classes for declaring repetitive methods. And access those methods by creating object of that particular class.

Comment: @Smita, I noticed some of your recent suggested edits. Please ease up on the `code formatting` (placing backticks around text) - that's meant for blocks of code, not to highlight words. Also, in this particular case, please note that "organize" is a perfectly valid (American) spelling.

Answer (score 0):

here is the apple solution to your problem. you can Implement a Shared iAd Banner in your app. here is docs for it.

[Technical Note TN2286](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2286/_index.html)

there are example codes for implementing the shared iAd in that doc. hope this helps you out.

p.s. here is the link to some sample codes.

https://developer.apple.com/iad/resources/

Comment: The given Technical Note TN2286 is somehow helpful. However the sample code actually does not use what the Tech Note says. For example iAdInterstitial sample code actually repeat delegate or ad-related codes in two different view controller .h files. I wonder if there's a way to have an Ad setup helper class, that holds related code, then each view controller will use the helper to set up ads.

Comment: You can. Write an so next class and import it in different views and access it in view did load or view will appear. I haven't done it that way but I'm sure it is possible. After all anything is possible.:)

Comment: Sorry I meant nsobject class.